# Can the DOM be modified for SQL injection attacks or other malicious attacks?

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, dom

I have buttons on my page that calls a JS function as so:

```
<button onclick="addProduct(100100)" type="button">Add</button>
```

(I'm doing it this way because I have multiples orders on the same page)

The JS function `addProduct(ordernum)` takes the order number and submits an ajax request to process the data into my database.

**PHP**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders ( ... ) VALUES ( ... ) WHERE sku = :sku AND ordernum = $_POST['ordernum']";
$statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':sku', $_GET['sku']);
$statement->execute();
```

In the above code I used `bindParam(`) on the `$_GET['sku']` variable to escape special characters that could be easily injected into the url (as you should).

However I did not do the same with `$_POST['ordernum']` because the value is stored on the DOM and cannot be modified. Or can it? That's my question. Can you modify information on the DOM for malicious attacks?

Obviously I could escape special characters using `bindParam()` just to be safe, but could an attacker change the value of my parameter on the DOM?

Comment: Yes, absolutely it can. Anything that comes from the browser cannot be trusted at all.

Comment: HTTP requests can be malicious. Assume all input is dangerous until you sanitize it thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to find another way to store the order number variable that represents each order on the DOM. The only way I can think of right now is to create a form and include hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also parameterize that because someone may post to your page not using your form.

Comment: Or patch the form with the developer tools. Or intercept and change the HTTP post data.

Comment: @Jeff Puckett I've never heard of that. Do you have a links for good documentation?

Comment: @David Well think about how you made your form. You have an `action` attribute that specifies what page to post to. I could make my own form however I want, and specify *your* page with my `action`

Comment: In addition to a hard form, it's trivial to indicate your page as the URL in purely JS methods, and a form (and the subsequent form submit) would never even be necessary. This is trivial in basic JavaScript, but [here's an obligatory jQuery link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to show how simple the interface is.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I see what you mean. But I did not use a form on my page at all. I was must posting the data with JS via ajax.

Comment: @David, yes, I realize that, but the way you're handling data server side is insecure because it allows unsanitized user input directly into the database. My form example is just one vector, but there are many possible exploits. I could make my own Ajax post to your page just the same. The form example is just the simplest one that came to mind. If I were going to hack you, then I would probably just use curl and post my malicious data that way to your server page.

Answer (score 0):

Anything stored client-side can be manipulated.

The request to your system is a simple POST request:

```
POST /somepage.php?sku=123 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 15

ordernum=ABCDEF
```

Any attacker could use a simple tool such as [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/) to manipulate the `ordernum` and achieve SQL Injection, so therefore you should parameterise *all* dynamic parameters (including any cookie or header values used).

Of course an attacker could change `ordernum` to another valid order and make changes to that instead of the one she is editing. To mitigate that, you should validate server-side that the current user has authorisation to edit the given `ordernum`.